# Which comic books about Iron Man and Superman should I read first?

Tags: marvel, dc, superman, suggested-order, iron-man

I never read comics, but now I want to start reading comic books in the Ironman and Superman universes, so where should I start and in what general order should I read the series?

Comment: Hi Andre, I'm not so sure qualifies as a clear well researched question...what have you read so far, what are your criteria? Do you mind skipping eras/ages? Are you after certain story arcs?

Comment: Ironically though, if Andre had asked for the [suggested-order](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) and then started reading at the first in the list, it probably would get a lot of up votes...

Comment: How is this *not constructive* but the other [tag:suggested-order] questions are okay and voted up beyond sanity?

Comment: The headline made me think the question was about crossovers. Darn.

Comment: @bitmask they all have a lot more to them, see here for my comic book suggested order request: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12041/3804

Answer (score 5):

Subjective answer will be subjective, however, DC just relaunched all of its Titles a few months ago - I would suggest starting with the [DC New 52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52) Universe Superman #1.

Marvel is relaunching a lot of their titles as well with their [Marvel NOW!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Now)

Both of these relaunches are for the benefit of people who are just starting comic book reading.

So, in my opinion - start with these relaunches #1 issues.

Comment: If you enjoy these and want to get your teeth in to other books/comic. Have a look at some collections. I myself have managed to get hold of some collections that have several stories in one. It means you don't need to fight to buy each issue separately. Check out local book stores, car boot sales backyard sales etc for a chance to buy some comic for cheap. My sister goes to a market shop and buys mine. 50p each in english money. So quite cheap. Any comic books that don't start at the beginning of a new story arc is usually a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to read Iron man, and I did it following the chronological order of the stories.

Luckily Marvel published a collection called *Marvel masterworks* which contains all the stories of Iron Man in the same order they have been published. Within 4 books I covered the first 20 years' of Iron Man/Tony Stark's life.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about general order. No really. With comic books, we are talking about DECADES of continuity, that contradicts itself on regular basis and DC just loves to reboot everything every now and then. Good stories generally tend to quickly fill you in.

I am not THAT versed in Iron Man, but Demon on the bottle is generally considered the must. And so is Deliverance.

With Superman, All-Star Superman, It's a Bird... and Red Son would be (together with single issue of Action comics "What's so funny about truth, justice and the American way") first to recommend. They are not part of any overall continuity but they manage to capture EXACTLY who he is. Supes also plays major role in many even books, including ever awesome Kingdom Come (which again, is stand alone continuity wise but Grant Morison just GETS Superman and manages to strike perfect counterpoint between paragon and the man, which is a thing many writers struggle ). I am personally fond of What Happened to the Man of Tomorrow, Secret Identity, New Krypton, Birthright and if you like (or at least tolerate) Batman, there's also World's Finest with it's double narration from both character's standpoints.